# How to freeze ahk Window Spy in W8

Tags: windows-8, freeze, autohotkey

My Window Spy says "Shift-Alt-Tab to freeze display" but ShfitAltTab winminimizes all windows. How can I freeze the Window Spy of autohotkey in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an [extended](http://dfiles.ru/files/rvsic382s) version that's has a different shortcut to freeze display information.

---

History:
Downloaded source version from [here](http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?pid=633#p633).
Changed to english menu.

Warranty:
File is free of any viruses, and works for me on my w81 x64.

Comment: i could not change to English menu... I'm in a loss at that Greek or Russian? website. Please help..

Comment: AMDG - follow the link he placed under *extended*, no the *here* link. That link worked fine for me, and the program is excellent. +1

Comment: great, but the previous Windows Spy is related to the program. Should I open this (new for me) Windows Spy as a regular program being opened?